# Time calculations based on multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to find if the punch in/punch out times match the total number of times they worked for every employee in 2016.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, PUNCH, 103), JOBDATE, EMPLOYEE, JOB, HOURS
FROM JOBTABLE
WHERE JOBDATE = convert(int, convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 112))
AND EMPLOYEE = 105
```

Table:

```
PUNCH   JOBDATE EMPLOYEE    JOB     HOURS
0600    20170123    105     AA785   7
1024    20170123    105     AA258   0.5
0600    20170123    105    LOGIN    0
1558    20170123    105    LOGIN    0
```

In this example on this day, employee 105 punched in at 600 and punched out at 1558 (3:58PM). That field is a char. There's no way to tell really the difference between a punch in and punch out besides a key field. The punch in is a lower number than the punch out, with no other rhyme or reason.

So this person worked about 10 hours. However, if you add up the time he put on to his jobs, it adds up to 7.5. I need to know that difference. If his total hours worked are less than what his punches are, then that's a big problem. I need to know the total sum for the year. So for 105 he is 2.5 hours short.

I don't know how to calculate the time worked because they are two separate rows. And then go through each row for each employee for each day. Can anyone help? Thank you so much!!

```
employee    jobdate    sumHours DiffHours   ScheduledHours
105         20170123    7.5    -2.466666    10
105         20170124    1.5    -6.5         8
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

More Test Data

```
Job         Hours   Punch   
123456X     0.98    0301    20160412
123451      1.75    0000    20160412
123452      1.27    0145    20160412
LOGIN       0       2345    20160412
LOGIN       0       0346    20160412
123453      0.25    2345    20160412
```

So this looks like he worked 3rd shift but he worked first.  I think that will have to be added in.  There is a shift column, thank goodness.  Anyways he worked 4.25 hours which is correct, but it's saying he was scheduled for 20.  minPunch  and maxPunch are 226 and 1425 and they should be 346 and 2345.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join two rows of data that match date and employee, but not punch; so you join the table against itself:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, A.PUNCH, 103) AS PUNCH_A, CONVERT(varchar, B.PUNCH, 103) AS PUNCH_B, A.JOBDATE, A.EMPLOYEE, A.JOB, A.HOURS + B.HOURS as TOTALHOURS
    FROM JOBTABLE A
    INNER JOIN JOBTABLE B
        ON A.JOBDATE = B.JOBDATE AND A.EMPLOYEE=B.EMPLOYEE AND A.JOB=B.JOB
           AND A.JOB <> 'LOGIN'
           AND A.PUNCH<B.PUNCH -- this is what makes sure A is the punch in and B punch out
    WHERE A.JOBDATE = convert(int, convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 112))
      AND A.EMPLOYEE = 105
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the punch to minutes and the hours to minutes. From there you can check if hours < (maxpunch - minpunch)

This might get you going in the right direction:

rextester: http://rextester.com/ZRXH77147

```
create table t (
    punch char(4)
  , jobdate char(8)
  , employee int 
  , job char(5)
  , hours decimal(5,2)
);

insert into t values
 ('0600','20170123',105,'AA785',7)
,('1024','20170123',105,'AA258',0.5)
,('0600','20170123',105,'LOGIN',0)
,('1558','20170123',105,'LOGIN',0);
```

query:

```
with cte as (
  select 

        employee
      , jobdate
      , minPunch = min(case 
                       when job = 'login' 
                         then (convert(int,left(Punch,2))*60.0)
                               +convert(int,right(Punch,2))
                       else null 
                       end
                    )
      , maxPunch = max(case 
                       when job = 'login' 
                         then (convert(int,left(Punch,2))*60.0)
                               +convert(int,right(Punch,2))
                       else null 
                       end
                    )
      , sumHours = sum(hours)
    from t
    group by 
        employee
      , jobdate
)
select 
      Employee
    , jobdate
    , SumHours
    , diffHours = convert(decimal(9,2)
                 ,round(((maxPunch-minPunch)-(sumHours*60.0))/60.0,1)
                 )
    , ScheduledHours = convert(decimal(9,2),round((maxPunch-minPunch)/60.0,1))
  from cte
```

returns:

```
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+----------------+
| Employee | jobdate  | SumHours | diffHours | ScheduledHours |
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+----------------+
|      105 | 20170123 | 7,50     | -2,50     | 10,00          |
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+----------------+
```

Comment: @CNL I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand. Can you update your question and clarify -- if you include desire results/output that would help.

Comment: @CNL if this answer works for you, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: why don't you try to supply new test data instead http://rextester.com/edit/ZRXH77147 ? Telling me something is wrong without showing me what it started as doesn't help.

Comment: @CNL If you added it to the rextester, click **`save edits`** enter a title and then click **`ok`**.

Comment: @CNL Add in the shift column too

Comment: Thank you so much.  Where is it? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @CNL I'm asking you to add in the shift column, I don't have that data.

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like 3rd shift people work differently, so I think I'll just add where shiftnumber = '1'.  Third shift people don't login until the end of their shift so the information would be inaccurate.  This system is so odd.